# AES encryption and decryption between C# and Ruby

Tags: c#, ruby, cryptography, encryption-symmetric

I'm currently working on a project where I need to port AES encryption between C# to Ruby and also provide backward compatibility. While both of them work well independently, I am facing an issue while encrypting data in C# and decrypting the same in Ruby.

While I have a gut feeling that there might be an issue with the way data is converted to string in ruby, I'm not sure about this as I'm not an expert in this field (SECURITY).

Any guidance on what needs to be corrected in the ruby code to decrypt encrypted text in C# will be helpful.

Below is my C# Code.

```cs
public class Encryption
{
    private const string SECRET = "readasecret";
    static byte[] KEY = new byte[] { 222, 11, 149, 155, 122, 97, 170, 8, 40, 250, 67, 227, 129, 147, 159, 81, 108, 136, 221, 41, 247, 146, 114, 133, 232, 31, 33, 196, 130, 88, 136, 238 };
    private static readonly byte[] Salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("o6MKe324346722kbM7c5");

    public static string Encrypt(string nonCrypted)
    {
        return EncryptStringAES(nonCrypted ?? string.Empty, SECRET);
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string encrypted)
    {
        return DecryptStringAES(encrypted, SECRET);
    }

    private static string EncryptStringAES(string plainText, string sharedSecret)
    {
        //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(plainText))
        //   throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sharedSecret))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("sharedSecret");

        string outStr;                  // Encrypted string to return
        RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;  // RijndaelManaged object used to encrypt the data.

        try
        {
            // generate the key from the shared SECRET and the salt
            var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sharedSecret, Salt);

            // Create a RijndaelManaged object
            aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
            aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);

            // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(KEY, aesAlg.IV);
            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // prepend the IV
                msEncrypt.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(aesAlg.IV.Length), 0, sizeof(int));
                msEncrypt.Write(aesAlg.IV, 0, aesAlg.IV.Length);
                using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                }
                outStr = Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Clear the RijndaelManaged object.
            if (aesAlg != null)
                aesAlg.Clear();
        }

        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
        return outStr;
    }

    private static string DecryptStringAES(string cipherText, string sharedSecret)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cipherText))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sharedSecret))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("sharedSecret");

        RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;

        // Declare the string used to hold
        // the decrypted text.
        string plaintext;

        try
        {
            // generate the key from the shared SECRET and the salt
            var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sharedSecret, Salt);

            // Create the streams used for decryption.                
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
                aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);
                // Get the initialization vector from the encrypted stream
                aesAlg.IV = ReadByteArray(msDecrypt);
                var decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(KEY, aesAlg.IV);
                using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Clear the RijndaelManaged object.
            if (aesAlg != null)
               aesAlg.Clear();
        }

        return plaintext;
    }

    private static byte[] ReadByteArray(Stream s)
    {
        var rawLength = new byte[sizeof(int)];
        if (s.Read(rawLength, 0, rawLength.Length) != rawLength.Length)
            throw new SystemException("Stream did not contain properly formatted byte array");

        var buffer = new byte[BitConverter.ToInt32(rawLength, 0)];
        if (s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) != buffer.Length)
            throw new SystemException("Did not read byte array properly");
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

and the equivalent Ruby code is below.

```
require 'pbkdf2'
require "openssl"
require "base64"
require "encrypted"
require "securerandom"

secret = "readasecret"
salt = "o6MKe324346722kbM7c5"
encrypt_this = "fiskbullsmacka med extra sovs"

rfc_db = PBKDF2.new(password: secret, salt: salt, iterations: 1000, key_length: 32, hash_function: :sha1).bin_string
key = rfc_db.bytes[0, 32]
puts key.inspect
cipherkey = key.pack('c*')


# ----------------- ENCRYPTION -------------------------
cipher = Encrypted::Ciph.new("256-128")
cipher.key = cipherkey
cipher.iv = cipher.generate_iv


encrypted_text = cipher.encrypt(encrypt_this)
# Convert string to byte[]
unpackENCString = encrypted_text.unpack("c*")
# Combine IV and data
combEncrypt = cipher.iv.unpack("c*").concat(encrypted_text.unpack("c*"))

# Convert byte[] to string
passingString = combEncrypt.pack("c*")

enc = Base64.encode64(passingString)

puts "Encrypted text :"+enc


# ----------------- DECRYPTION -------------------------

plain = Base64.decode64(enc)

passingbyteArray = plain.unpack("c*")

rfc_db = PBKDF2.new(password: secret, salt: salt, iterations: 1000, key_length: 32, hash_function: :sha1).bin_string
key = rfc_db.bytes[0, 32]
decipherkey = key.pack('c*')

decrypt_this = passingbyteArray[16,passingbyteArray.length() - 16].pack("c*")               #from above
decipher = Encrypted::Ciph.new("256-128")
cipher.key = decipherkey     #key used above to encrypt
cipher.iv = passingbyteArray[0,16].pack("c*")      #initialization vector used above
decrypted_text = cipher.decrypt(decrypt_this)

puts "Decrypted text: "+decrypted_text
```

Comment: It looks like you generate the IV on both sides. The IV needs to be consistent on both sides. You don't need to protect the IV; it can be exchanged in clear text

Comment: @Flydog57: Yes, the IV is generated on both sides, however, the IV value remains the same whenever it is generated. So the IV is not the cause of the problem here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73881872/how-to-encrypt-with-ruby-in-aes-128-ctr-mode
can you help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the posted C# code, a key derivation via PBKDF2 is implemented, but it's not used. Instead, the hard-coded key `KEY` is applied. This may have been done for testing purposes.

In the following, not the hard coded key, but the derived key is considered. For this in the C# code in `aesAlg.CreateEncryptor()` and in `aesAlg.CreateDecryptor()` instead of `KEY` `aesAlg.Key` must be passed, to which the derived key was assigned before.

The C# code concatenates after encryption the size of the IV (to 4 bytes), the IV and the ciphertext in this order. On decryption the corresponding separation takes place.
Note that storing the size of the IV is actually not necessary, since it's known: the sizeof the IV is equal to the block size, and is thus 16 bytes for AES.
In the following, the concatenation of the IV size is kept for simplicity.

In the Ruby code, various crypto ibraries are used, although *openssl* is actually sufficient. Therefore, the following implementation applies *openssl* only:

The key derivation using PBKDF2 is:

```rb
require "openssl"
require "base64"

# Key derivation (PBKDF2)
secret = "readasecret"
salt = "o6MKe324346722kbM7c5"
key = OpenSSL::KDF.pbkdf2_hmac(secret, salt: salt, iterations: 1000, length: 32, hash: "sha1")
```

The encryption is:

```rb
# Encryption
plaintext = "fiskbullsmacka med extra sovs"
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-256-CBC')
cipher.encrypt
cipher.key = key
nonce = cipher.random_iv # random IV
cipher.iv = nonce
ciphertext = cipher.update(plaintext) + cipher.final
# Concatenation
sizeIvCiphertext = ['10000000'].pack('H*').concat(nonce.concat(ciphertext))
sizeIvCiphertextB64 =  Base64.encode64(sizeIvCiphertext)
puts sizeIvCiphertextB64 # e.g. EAAAAC40tnEeaRtwutravBiH8vpn4vtjk6s9CAq/XEbyGTGMPwxENInIoAqWlZvR413Aqg==
```

and the decryption:

```rb
# Separation
sizeIvCiphertext = Base64.decode64(sizeIvCiphertextB64)
size = sizeIvCiphertext[0, 4]
iv = sizeIvCiphertext [4, 16]
ciphertext = sizeIvCiphertext[4+16, sizeIvCiphertext.length-16]
# Decryption
decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-256-CBC')
decipher.decrypt
decipher.key = key
decipher.iv = iv
decrypted = decipher.update(ciphertext) + decipher.final
puts decrypted # fiskbullsmacka med extra sovs
```

The ciphertext generated with this can be decrypted with the C# code. Likewise, a ciphertext of the C# code can be decrypted with the above Ruby code.

---

Keep in mind that both codes contain a vulnerability. The codes use a *static* salt for the key derivation, which is insecure. Instead, a random salt should be generated for each key derivation. Just like the IV, the salt is not secret and is usually passed along with the IV and the ciphertext, e.g. *salt | IV | ciphertext*.
Also, for PBKDF2, an iteration count of 1000 is generally too small.

Comment: For ruby version <= 2.3.3, we can use the following password derivative function

digest = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new
key = OpenSSL::PKCS5.pbkdf2_hmac("rewsdfvcx", "o6MKe6722kbM7c5", 1000, 32, digest)