# Ruby: Decrypt content encrypted with AES algorithm which uses ECB mode and PKCS5 padding

Tags: ruby, aes

I am calling an API which gives me back a string encrypted using AES algorithm. The result of AES algorithm is encoded using Base64. The AES algorithm uses ECB mode and PKCS5 padding.

With ruby decrypting AES is rather easy. So I tried the usual ways:

- Tried the [AES gem](https://github.com/chicks/aes) by `chicks`
- Digged through the [`Cipher` documentation](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/OpenSSL/Cipher.html) to find a suitable algorithm

I ended up with a lot of "try and error" because it was not totally clear to me how to pass `PKCS5 padding` into the decryption function.
All I found is [this class](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKCS5.html) which refers to `PKCS5` but its not totally clear how to pass my key and content in there.

So I tried many possible AES/ECB combinations like this:

```
decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(128, :ECB)
decipher.key = Base64.decode64(key)
encrypted = Base64.decode64(encrypted)
decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted) + decipher.final
```

but this throws:

> `final': wrong final block length (OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError)

I am not an encryption specialist so I am in a dead end here. Maybe you have a hint in the right direction.

How can I decrypt AES encrypted content using my key and ECB mode with PKCS5 padding?

Comment: If you Base64 decode the key, it is 16 bytes long.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68088758/9014097) you can find an example for AES and PKCS5 padding (focus on the decryption part and ignore the separation part of this). The mode used is CBC, which requires an IV. You apply ECB and therefore don't need an IV (but ECB is insecure for that very reason).

Comment: updated my reply above

Comment: @Topaco good hint but still not there

Comment: The code works, see [here](https://replit.com/@3hK8cL8H24hwiS7/TerrificPutridWaterfall). If it doesn't work for your data, the data may be inconsistent.

Comment: I can confirm it works. Thanks for your help! @Topaco