# how to encode and decode a json array to base64 in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am receiving array which has a json data in it from a html form how to convert that to base64 encoded data

the error by compiler is

{:name=>"test", :class=>"abc", :roll=>"1122", :address=>"xyz", :pincode=>"12345"}
internal:pack:144:in `pack': no implicit conversion of Array into String (TypeError) from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/base64.rb:39:in` encode64'
from ./test.rb:4:in `'

My code used is-

```
require "base64"
data = [{"name":"test","class":"abc","roll":"1122","address":"xyz","pincode":"12345"}]
puts data
enc = Base64.encode64(data)
puts enc
dec = Base64.decode64(enc)
puts dec
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the following should work for you: (I used the structure from the comment rather than the Post)

**JS**:

```
var obj = [{"edmc":"78787041","house_no":"987654234","type":"0","abc_type":"AABB","bbcname":"Unknown","abc_nick_name":"notKnown", "allot":"1.00", "hhic":"BAC1235","address1":"abcdw","city":"abcde", "state":"UU", "pincode":"123456", "email":"anccss@gmail.com","phone":"1234567898"}]; 
btoa(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Results in:

```
W3siZWRtYyI6Ijc4Nzg3MDQxIiwiaG91c2Vfbm8iOiI5ODc2NTQyMzQiLCJ0eXBlIjoiMCIsImFiY190eXBlIjoiQUFCQiIsImJiY25hbWUiOiJVbmtub3duIiwiYWJjX25pY2tfbmFtZSI6Im5vdEtub3duIiwiYWxsb3QiOiIxLjAwIiwiaGhpYyI6IkJBQzEyMzUiLCJhZGRyZXNzMSI6ImFiY2R3IiwiY2l0eSI6ImFiY2RlIiwic3RhdGUiOiJVVSIsInBpbmNvZGUiOiIxMjM0NTYiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImFuY2Nzc0BnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJwaG9uZSI6IjEyMzQ1Njc4OTgifV0=
```

**Ruby**

```
obj = [{"edmc":"78787041","house_no":"987654234","type":"0","abc_type":"AABB","bbcname":"Unknown","abc_nick_name":"notKnown", "allot":"1.00", "hhic":"BAC1235","address1":"abcdw","city":"abcde", "state":"UU", "pincode":"123456", "email":"anccss@gmail.com","phone":"1234567898"}]
Base64.strict_encode64(obj.to_json)
```

Results in

```
W3siZWRtYyI6Ijc4Nzg3MDQxIiwiaG91c2Vfbm8iOiI5ODc2NTQyMzQiLCJ0eXBlIjoiMCIsImFiY190eXBlIjoiQUFCQiIsImJiY25hbWUiOiJVbmtub3duIiwiYWJjX25pY2tfbmFtZSI6Im5vdEtub3duIiwiYWxsb3QiOiIxLjAwIiwiaGhpYyI6IkJBQzEyMzUiLCJhZGRyZXNzMSI6ImFiY2R3IiwiY2l0eSI6ImFiY2RlIiwic3RhdGUiOiJVVSIsInBpbmNvZGUiOiIxMjM0NTYiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImFuY2Nzc0BnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJwaG9uZSI6IjEyMzQ1Njc4OTgifV0=
```